# Sharepoint list , Image column does not show images for shared users

Tags: sharepoint

In my Share point List I have an image column, that shows pic as a thumbnail for each row , when hovered it shows a slightly large image and when checked on , it opens the full image in a separate tab. The issue is when I share this list internally the users cannot see the image inserted in this column.
Shared users have "view only" permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my tests, if the user only has View-Only permission for this list (don't have permission to this site), this user really cannot view picture in the Image column.

**Here is my test:**

1.This is a SharePoint list with Image column

[image]

2.The test account: MiKi has no permission to the SharePoint site and has View-Only permission to this list

[image]

[image]

3.Access this list with test account

[image]

If you **give the test account permission at the site level (can access this site)**, the test account can view picture in the Image column normally.

**For example:**
1.Grant View-Only permission for test account at the site level

[image]

2.Access this list with test account

[image]

Comment: Thank you for resolving the issue ,  it got fixed using your detailed explanation, the screenshots helped a lot .Appreciate your help,